# Dynamic return type in interface

Tags: go

There is the next code:

**UserModel.go**

```
type UserModel struct{login, password}
var EntityArr = map[string]UserModel{}
func GetAll() map[string]UserModel {
    uuidString := uuid.New().String()
    user := Entity{Login: "myLogin", Password: "MyPassword"}
    EntityArr[uuidString] = user

    return EntityArr
}
```

**PostModel.go**

```
type PostModel struct{title, description}
func GetAll() map[string]PostModel {/* like in UserModel */}
```

**UserController.go**

```
type ControllerUser struct{}
func GetAll()map[string]UserModel { rertun UserModel.GetAll() }
```

**PostController.go**

```
type ControllerPost struct{}
func GetAll()map[string]PostModel { rertun PostModel.GetAll() }
```

I try to dynamic detect necessary controller:

**main.go**

```
var currentController = Intfc
switch entity {
  "user" : currentController = UserController.ControllerUser{}
  "post" : currentController = PostController.ControllerPost{}
}
currentController.GetAll()
```

To do this I need a common interface

**Interface.go**

```
type Intfc interface {
    ShowAll() ???
}
```

What type of return data the function (in interface) returns?

Comment: No, you cannot do that, at least not with an interface with a `ShowAll` method.

Comment: Your comments are completely inaccurate. Example: `func GetAll() map[string]UserModel {/* return array of UserModel */}` -- No, it does not return an array of `UserModel`, it returns a map of `string` to `UserModel`.

Comment: @leafbebop , if ShowAll() will a procedure (return nothing) it'll be work, but for function - doesn't work. Do you have another way to solve my question?

Comment: @Flimzy, I corrected mo code

Comment: @kohhop - your code still won't work, since `switch` statement shall be companied by `case` keyword and `Intfc` is not a value. As for your question, it is not clear unless you specify how you want your code look like (say, an API signature), it is unclear what approaches you should use. May be have a look on `reflect` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!
@leafbebop, @Flimzy and someone else look to https://github.com/arturturundaev/simpleCRUDproject